# Java compile error 'package does not exist'

Tags: java, compiler-errors, package

I created two packages.class files (util.Displayable & school.Teacher).  Teacher class will implement the Displayable interface from util.  When I compiled it, I am receiving 'teacher.java:2: error: package util does not exist'.  The other errors were a result from the util package 'not existing'.  I deleted the util file & tried again but got the same error.  Any ideas on why util package cant be found?
Thanks!

util.Displayable file

```
package util;

public interface Displayable {
    public abstract String display();
}
```

school.Teacher file

```
package school;
import util.Displayable;

  public class Teacher extends Person implements Displayable {
    private String subject;

    public Teacher() {
    }

    public Teacher (String firstName, String lastName, String subject){
        this.setFirstName(firstName);
        this.setLastName(lastName);
        this.setSubject(subject);    
    }        
        public String getSubject() {
          return subject;
        }

        public void setSubject(String subject){
        this.subject = subject;
        }  

        @Override
        public String display() {
          return this.getFullName() + "teaches" + this.getSubject();
        }
    }
```

Compile Error

```
C:\WEBUCATOR\JVA102_2.0.2\DanProject\school>javac teacher.java
teacher.java:2: error: package util does not exist
import util.Displayable;
           ^
teacher.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
  public class Teacher extends Person implements Displayable {
                               ^
  symbol: class Person
teacher.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
  public class Teacher extends Person implements Displayable {
                                                 ^
  symbol: class Displayable
teacher.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        this.setFirstName(firstName);
            ^
  symbol: method setFirstName(String)
teacher.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        this.setLastName(lastName);
            ^
  symbol: method setLastName(String)
teacher.java:23: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
teacher.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
          return this.getFullName() + "teaches" + this.getSubject();
                     ^
  symbol: method getFullName()
7 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have added jre path in environment variables or not added path at all.

Answer (score 0):

Directory structure (and capitalization) matter! Rename `teacher.java` to `Teacher.java` and create a `util` folder. Put the files in the `util` package in the `util` folder, and run

```
javac util\*.java
```

Even better would be using a tool like `ant`, `maven` or `sbt` to manage your builds (and/or an IDE).

Comment: The OP may also have to set the classpath to the other directory when compiling: `javac -classpath .\util:.\school\ Teacher.java`